# Importing an image is importing a base64 encoded string (electron-webpack)

Tags: webpack, electron

I'm using electron-webpack and am not able to import an image. I have it located at `src/renderer/images/logo.png` (I also have a .svg that I have tried with the same result) and I have tried both:

```
const logo = require("../images/logo.png");
```

and

```
import logo from "../images/logo.png";
```

I get a broken image, so I used https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file to convert the base64 and the content is:

```
module.exports = __webpack_public_path__ + "logo.png?41d52b7bd0bbc9f306e6075f8b7f80a0";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your expectation: you used electron-webpack (https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-webpack/blob/e95cc47f7e0274d1e06f5ade6abf2e5745c8df82/packages/electron-webpack/src/targets/RendererTarget.ts#L45-L48)

which specifies url-loader for image:

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "url-loader",
          options: configureFileLoader("imgs")
        }
```

and url-loader will import resource as b64 (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader)

> A loader for webpack which transforms files into base64 URIs

There is nothing wrong and images are imported correctly as expected.

If you'd like to import resource in different way, you may need change configuration to use different loader as you desired.

Comment: My expectation is that I get something usable in the src attribute of a img tag. The base64 that is being imported is not an Image, it is javascript code ..

Comment: it is b64 encoded _image_, and it's following what you have configured to do so. 1. it is still valid image so you can use it 2. if you'd like to import image in different way configuration should be updated to use different loader.

Comment: This is a b64 encoded path to image, not image.